# How to retrieve both caller-name and carrier from Twilio in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

Im having problems working with the twilio-api for node.

i wrote this code:

```
let typeArray = ['caller-name','carrier'];
this.client.phoneNumbers(phoneNumberToCheck).get({
  type: typeArray
}, (error, number) =>  {
  // working on the number data results
  // ...
});
```

The problem is that i dont get ANY of them(carrier/caller-name) - although passing array to argument 'type' is the way to do it in other languages(php,c#..) but it doesnt work on node.js, instead i get this:

```
// -> get 
{
  "caller_name":null,
  "country_code":"US",
  "phone_number":"+123456789",
  "national_format":"(248) 123-456",
  "carrier":null,
  "add_ons":null,
  "url":"https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+123456789",
  "callerName":null,
  "countryCode":"US",
  "phoneNumber":"+123456789",
  "nationalFormat":"(248) 123-456",
  "addOns":null
}
```

note: if i send each one separately (only carrier or only caller-name) - i get the partial information for each.

how can i get both in one request in node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You should be calling the [Lookups API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups) in Node this way:

```
client.lookups.phoneNumbers.get(phoneNumber)
  .fetch({
    type: ['carrier', 'caller-name']
  },
  function(err, result) {
    // do something
  }
)
```

The docs are a little lacking in Node.js on the [Lookups documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups) and I will raise that with the team.

Comment: Tnks a lot - is it available in version 2.11.1 as well?
cause the api/syntax is different .

Comment: I'm afraid the v2 library didn't handle array parameters correctly. I recommend upgrading to the v3 library as v2 will only be officially supported until 31/08/2017. There is a [migration guide available here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node/migration-guide).